# Upgrading from angular 2 to 4.0.0-rc1

Tags: angular

I have been working with Angular 2 recently and am relatively new to it.

In view of the approaching release, I decided to upgrade to the latest version which is the first Angular 4 release candidate. I tried to use the suggested command which is:

```
npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router,animations}@next --save
```

This command failed, and I understand from other posts that this syntax is available in bash, which I am not familiar with.

I set my path to my project folder and then I tried to install each package individually using:

```
npm install @angular/common@next --save
```

for each package.
This seemed to partially work, but there were a number of dependency warnings given.

The result now is that I can no longer use **ng serve** and I think my setup is somewhat *broken* to say the least.
Can someone please suggest a way of uninstalling angular (globally and locally) using node so I can have a go at installing angular 4 rc1 and the latest angular cli from scratch.

Comment: So you're using Angular CLI? Instead of running around it this way, what I might try to do is modify the package.json file. If you look in there you'll see the angular packages (I just created a project with ng new myproj) and the versions say 2.2.1 (on my machine anyway). You could just edit that info, delete your node_modules directory, and run npm install. That'll reinstall all your packages and dependendies. Note that new packages often require newer dependencies, but at least this way, when you run npm install, you'll see those errors/warnings, and can spot fix (or see it won't work yet).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response Tim. From what I have learned about package.json, your suggestion makes sense and I will try it.

Comment: Really, downvotes without explanations shouldn't be allowed. I can't imagine why anybody would downvote this question. For the record I not only thought it was a good question, but I learned something today. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put some time into this and got it working (as far as I can see).

Here's what you have to do (rather, here's what I did a couple of times to test and it works). Do these steps in sequence.

Create your project with angular cli as usual.

As usual, go into that project directory.

Delete node_modules.

Install webpack individually (to ensure you get latest version ^2).

```
npm install webpack
```

Replace your package.json file with the file below, then run npm install.

Run ng serve

Project starts up.

Note that when running ng serve, you will see 20+ of these errors. They don't seem to prevent the project from running and I don't see any errors in the browser console.

```
[default] /Users/tcoz/web-dev-projects/angular4/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/typings/src/dom/dom_renderer.d.ts:58:41 
    Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
```

One other thing: I don't have TS installed globally. Not sure if that matters, but it might. Make sure you are running latest (^2.2.1).

package.json (note that a number of things are updated, not just angular, some of the dependency messages were confusing until I just installed webpack 2):

```
{
  "name": "angular4",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.0-rc.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0-rc.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.21",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.0-beta.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say install webpack individually, do you mean that it should be installed into the project folder?

Comment: Yes. Delete node_modules, install webpack with the command I show above (will install webpack 2), do the rest. I don't use any global flags, etc.

Comment: Appreciate the clarification. I did what you suggested and still not quite there, due to the fact that I installed the new version of Angular CLI as well, so needed to install this globally and locally. It now works.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. I think you could get it all to work locally, but at this point whatever works. I'm sure the CLI team will be streamlining this sometime soon though.

Comment: Incidentally, when you state that you don't use global flags, do you mean that for any package? ie. Do you only ever install into your projects? I must admit to being bewildered by the need for multiple installs in Angular, but hey, until I have a better understanding I'm happy to progress!

Comment: I try never to use global installs if I can help it, at least not on my dev machine. Other opinions may vary, but I work on a lot of projects on the same machine. Depending on what version of a given framework, build system, whatever I'm using, globals can sometimes create hard-to-fix errors. Even Webpack (surprisingly) recommends per-project installs (on the new webpack 2 site). By putting your commands in the package.json file pointing to the node_modules you want to run (webpack, etc), you don't have to worry about typing paths etc. It also easy to get rid of whichever one you want.

Comment: @TimConsolazio I am currently specifying `typings` in the dependencies. Can i add `@types/core-js` in addition to `typings` to resolve the following error:
`ERROR in [default] node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/iter‌​able_differs.d.ts:15‌​:47 Cannot find name 'Iterable'.`

Comment: I don't really bother much with TS anymore, I just don't see the need, especially once ES7 comes along. If I see something though I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

In package.json I replaced the version number of the angular components (2.4.9) with the current new version (4.0.0-rc.3) and also spec'd the @angular/router to 4.0.0-rc.3.  Build went fine except for warnings from some kendo components. Despite the warnings, the kendo components behaved as expected.